# how to put outer line for a table using itextsharp in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, pdf-generation, itext

I'am creating a 2*2 table on pdf file. I Just want to put outer border for the table, No need to show the inner cells border. I have tried like this

```
 var back= new PdfPTable(2); //table for back
           back.DefaultCell.Border = 1;
           PdfPCell cell20 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("cell1", body));
           cell20.Border = 0;
           back.AddCell(cell20);

           PdfPCell cell21 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("cell2", body));
           cell21.Border = 0;
           cell21.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
           back.AddCell(cell21);

           PdfPCell cell22 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("cell3"));
           cell22.Border = 0;
           cell22.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
           back.AddCell(cell22);

           PdfPCell cell23 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("cell4", body));
           cell23.Border = 0;
           cell23.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
           back.AddCell(cell23);
```

but it results a table without any border, please help

Comment: you need to define a second table and then wrap this table in it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a table event, for instance:

```
public class OuterBorder implements PdfPTableEvent {
    public void tableLayout(PdfPTable table, float[][] width, float[] height,
            int headerRows, int rowStart, PdfContentByte[] canvas) {
        float widths[] = width[0];
        float x1 = widths[0];
        float x2 = widths[widths.length - 1];
        float y1 = height[0];
        float y2 = height[height.length - 1];
        PdfContentByte cb = canvas[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];
        cb.rectangle(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
        cb.stroke();
    }
}
```

As you can see, we use the `width` and `height` parameter passed to the `tableLayout()` method to define the borders of a rectangle, and we draw that rectangle to the `LINECANVAS`.

For this table event to work, you need to declare it to the table. In your case, that would be:

```
back.setTableEvent(new OuterBorder());
```

Note that my code is written in Java based on the [PressPreviews](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=95) example from my book. For the corresponding C# code, please consult [the iTextSharp examples](http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C05).